# Sending Email Using SMTP Bluehost Server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, smtp

I use **ASP.NET WEB API** and I want to send an email from my application from an email created by https://www.bluehost.com/

Here is the configuration in the **web.config** file:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="example@domain.com">
            <network host="mail.domain.com"
             port="465"
             userName="example@domain.com"
             password="*****"
             enableSsl="true"   />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Here is my code:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Timeout = 120000;
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("fromMailAddress@domain.com", "toMailAddress@gmail.com"); 
mail.Body = "Here is the body of my email";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

I am receiving the following error:

> Network Error (tcp_error) 
>   A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
>   The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Note that I have tried configuring **SMTP** directly in the above code, but still it didn't work.

I had tested from host **smtp.gmail.com** and it worked fine, so I guess the issue is from the new host.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For SMTP, I used port 26 and mail.company.com. My host server is bluehost.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below code segment.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Port = 465; // can check port for ssl - 587 and non ssl - 25
smtpClient.Host = "mail.domain.com";
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("example@domain.com","password");

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("donotreply@domain.com", "sendtomyemail@domain.com", "test", "test");
mail.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: At first I got a timeout error, so I set smtpClient.Timeout = 100000;
Then the network error reappeared.

Comment: please check your firewall setting. it must be allowed from there.